# Python selenium get text from href element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have few links with URLs and text inside them. I would like to extract the link and text at the same time. But now my method only extracts the url link.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="4545"></td><td></td><td><img src="/icons/ecblank.gif" border="0" height="1" width="16" alt=""><font size="2"><a href="/names.com/myIDHERE">MY 1st TETX IS HERE</a></font></td><td></td><td></td><td><font size="2"><a href="/names.com/myIDHERE">Teresa David</a></font></td><td><font size="2"></font></td></tr>
```

Python code:

```
elems = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already selected the elements you get the texts simply with `elem.text`:

```
elems = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(f'{elem.text}: {elem.get_attribute("href")}')
```

Comment: thanks this works, but only doesn't print the date on the same line. @tranbi

Comment: you mean the text right? I updated the answer to print text and url on the same line (separated by `:`)